# Needed permission constant not available at Manifest class

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to check for a specific permission with `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context ,Manifest.permission.<permission>` but the only permission available as constant there is `Manifest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`, although in my manifest I have declared many others as well

```
<manifest package="packagename"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

It´s the project typical import like `import <projectname>.Manifest`
Why is that? Went something wrong with the file generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `Manifest`. You are using `<appPackage>.Manifest`, while what you want in this case is [`android.Manifest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.html).